# save checkbox value in access database with vb.net 2010 (wpf c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

guy how can i insert the value of checkbox in access database or any database.

i tried any of this sql statement but it still give me error: **OleDbException was Unhandled. Data type mismatch in criteria expression.** and it's pointing to myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

note that allowviewpsr is a boolean type of field in ms access database or the one with YES/NO. :) chkviewpsr is mycheckbox

```
SQL = "UPDATE `RUsers` SET `allowviewpsr` = '" + chkviewpsr.IsChecked.Value + "' WHERE `idnum`= '" + txtblkuserid.Text  + "' AND `fullname`= '" + txtblkusername.Text + "'";
```

also this:

```
SQL = "UPDATE `RUsers` SET `allowviewpsr` = '" + chkviewpsr.IsChecked + "' WHERE `idnum`= '" + txtblkuserid.Text  + "' AND `fullname`= '" + txtblkusername.Text + "'";
```

and also this:

```
SQL = "UPDATE `RUsers` SET `allowviewpsr` = '" + chkviewpsr + "' WHERE `idnum`= '" + txtblkuserid.Text  + "' AND `fullname`= '" + txtblkusername.Text + "'";
```

and here's my connector:

```
myCommand.CommandText = SQL;
myCommand.Connection = MyNewOleDbConnection;
myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

**EDITED:**
hi anandkumar thanks for the quick replay i tried NonQuery but it gives same error as above

```
SQL = "UPDATE `RWMUsers` SET `allowviewpsr` = '" + chkviewpsr.IsChecked.Value + "' WHERE `idnum`= '" + txtblkuserid.Text  + "' AND `fullname`= '" + txtblkusername.Text + "'";
myCommand.CommandText = SQL;
myCommand.Connection = MyNewOleDbConnection;
myAdapter.UpdateCommand = myCommand;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Snapshot of my Access Database** :(

[image]

Comment: there is some bad practice in this code ;) you should read about query injection and how to avoid it.

Comment: can you give me sample on how can i create a right sql statement... thanks :(

Comment: @KenshiHemura, Please upload the table constraints and column types of "RWMUsers"

Comment: @KenshiHemura use Parameters to deal with variables in your sql queries.

Comment: @Felice Pollano thanks for the reply.. im sorry im not that good in c#.. can you give me an example if you dont mind. thanks :(

Comment: @KenshiHemura the example in the Anandkumar reply contain bot the solution for you and an example in using parameters :)

Comment: @Felice Pollano and to you also thank you so much... :) now i know how to use parameters... found very simple explanation at this blog [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Use

```
myAdapter.UpdateCommand = myCommand;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Reference:**

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand.aspx