# Connection String over network for oledb

Tags: connection-string, oledbconnection

What can be the problem with following connectionStrings

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\otherPCName\SmoeSharedFolder\test.mdb;";
```

Or

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\192.168.14\SmoeSharedFolder\test.mdb;";
```

No Problem with following connection String, when i access database on that PC *otherCP*

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=D:\SmoeSharedFolder\test.mdb;";
```

Also I can open a text file from other PC using this path. This tells the path should be valid

```
\\otherPCName\SmoeSharedFolder\hi.txt
```

I have seen connection strings for network so I think they should work but how?

Comment: Does your application user have access to that network path?

Comment: Off course that is why hi.txt can be opened

Comment: What error are you receiving with the first example? (The second example is not a valid IP address: http://192.168.14.

Comment: @rontornambe. Thanks and sorry for ignorance. I was get error `specified file cannot be opened`. It is working now with `192.168.1.14`. In first one I had also wrong 'PC NAME' it was `sam-pc` and I was trying `sampc`. Before posting the question I had cared everything, but somehow could not sort it out, as I was not expecting mistake in both cases.

Comment: I had been able to open `hi.txt` because there I was using copy paste the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\otherPCName\SmoeSharedFolder\test.mdb;";

string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source=\\192.168.1.14\SmoeSharedFolder\test.mdb;";
```

Both strings are valid to access database from a network PC. If your database file exists in a folder to which **you have permissions** => Exists in a Shared folder. **You will be able to write (update/insert)**  only if you have write permissions as well.

I was getting error `specified file cannot be opened`. Because I had problem both in using `otherPCName` and IP `192.168.14`. (For otherpcname I was using sampc but it was sam-pc).