# C# `INSERT INTO` MS Access db not inserting

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledb

so I'm working on a database program and it requires to insert a Log into the database using INSERT INTO command, however the table remains empty after executing the query. Please help! Thanks~ Here are the codes.

```
    //Predefined connection string
    OleDbConnection vcon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\data.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxx;");




    private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log("StartUp", "System", "NULL", "System StartUp");
    }

    public void Log(string Type, string User, string Table_affected, string Remarks)
    {

        string NowDateStamp = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", 
                              DateTime.Now.Day.ToString(), 
                              DateTime.Now.Month.ToString(), 
                              DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
        string NowTimeStamp = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}",
                              DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString(),
                              DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString(),
                              DateTime.Now.Second.ToString());
        string tempSQL = string.Format("INSERT INTO 'Log' VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}')",
                                        NowDateStamp,
                                        NowTimeStamp,
                                        Type,
                                        User,
                                        Table_affected,
                                        Remarks);
        vcon.Open();
        OleDbCommand vcom = new OleDbCommand(tempSQL, vcon);
        vcom.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Done"); // <-- This MessageBox isn't even showing.
        vcon.Close();
    }
```

So basically the program will start up then log the time, however it seemed done nothing to the database, anyone can help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Are you seeing any runtime errors? Also do you have to use Access - SQLServer CE4.0 is a great alternative?

Comment: Run in debug mode, guessing there is an error in there somewhere otherwise you'd get the messagebox, as you indicated.

Comment: For your timestamps, you could just use `var nowDateStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");` and `var nowTimeStamp  = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");`, not really related to your question but may make your code more readable =)

Comment: Your INSERT INTO command is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should always [use parameters with QleDbCommand](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5893956/19241) instead of formatting strings with values.

Comment: +1 for Danko. You should NEVER use formatted string in all of your query string.

Answer (score 6):

Executing the query causes an exception, but somewhere that exception is caught and ignored.

You are using a string literal where the table name should be. It should either be just the identifier:

```
INSERT INTO Log VALUES ...
```

or the identifier inside square brackets:

```
INSERT INTO [Log] VALUES ...
```

Comment: +1 - However, I would recommend always using Square brackets. You will need to for reserved words and column names with spaces anyway, so I would always do this for consistency

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
INSERT INTO 'Log' VALUES
```

With this one:

```
INSERT INTO Log VALUES
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I've figured out that the query itself is alright, however since the table has its own primary key, such that inserting to the table will be 7 items instead of 6. Therefore I've removed the primary key and everything is fine now =] Thanks for the help! =]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have said I would guess that you have a syntax error too. You should be specifying into which columns you want your values to be inserted.

```
INSERT INTO Log (<column1>,<column2>,...)
VALUES (<Value to insert into column1>, <Value to insert into column 2>,...)
```