# INSERT error ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ms-access

Hey I get an error saying there is something wrong with my code when inserting into a database, can't quite find it. The error suggests it is something in the INSERT statement, but appears on the line `"cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"`. I'm using an access database.

Error: **Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.**

```
con.Open();
string mysql; 
mysql = "INSERT INTO [User](FirstName,Surname,Age,HouseNumber,PostCode,Username,Password) 
         VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", tbFirstName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", tbSurname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", int.Parse(tbAge.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", tbAddress1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", tbPostCode.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", tbUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7", tbPassword.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? How does your table look?

Comment: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.

The database fields reflect that of the insert statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you add parameters with value you need to convert it to matching type, if age is number then

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", int.Parse(tbAge.Text));
```

and also [`User` is key word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335) you can try with

```
"INSERT INTO [User] ([FirstName], [Surname], [Age], [HouseNumber], [PostCode], [Username], [Password]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```

Comment: Add this, thank you, but still getting the same error message.

Comment: @ChristopherDunne `[PASSWORD]` is also reserved word, better that you can test by adding `[]` for all columns and table names

Comment: Fixed it, thanks, all these complicated answers and it was just that :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried replacing the `?` with your parameters?

Correction: I believe you have to add `OleDBParameters` like so:

```
con.Open();
string mysql; 
mysql = "INSERT INTO User(FirstName,Surname,Age,HouseNumber,PostCode,Username,Password) 
     VALUES (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(mysql, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
{
    new OleDbParameter("@p1", tbFirstName.Text),
    new OleDbParameter("@p2", tbSurname.Text),
           ...
});
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Access databases require "?"

Comment: Tried it just incase, did nothing. Error remains, thanks though.

Comment: There appears to be a bracket missing, where is it closed, will give it a go, cheers.

Comment: Now I'm getting... ArgumentException was unhandled by user code... The OleDbParameter is already contained by another OleDbParameterCollection.

Comment: `The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the question mark (?) placeholder must be used`

Comment: It's ok I changed it back to "?" and this new fix seems to have created more problems?

Comment: What does your connection string look like, are you using Jet or ACE.  the above suggestion was taken from a previously accepted answer in similar topic.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database