# Error while inserting data into a access database in vb 2010

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am using the below code for saving data into a MS-Access 2007 table. But it throw a expression as follows:

```
{"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0')'."}
```

I have attached the code below:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Daily_EB_Consumption (EB_S1, EB_S2, EB_S3, EB_S4, EB_S5, EB_Indus, EB_LH, EB_Total, EB_Date) " & _
    " VALUES(" & Me.txt_S1.Text & "','" & _
      Me.txt_S2.Text & "','" & Me.txt_S3.Text & "','" & Me.txt_S4.Text & "','" & _
      Me.txt_S5.Text & "','" & Me.txt_Indus.Text & "','" & Me.txt_LH.Text & "','" & _
      Me.txt_Total.Text & "','" & Me.dt_EB.Value & "')"
```

Please anyone help with this error

Answer (score 1):

You have used the apostrophe but only on the right side. You have to wrap the values in apostrophes:

```
VALUES('" & Me.txt_S1.Text & "', ...
```

But you are open for SQL-Injection, so you should use parameters.

[using parameters inserting data into access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)

Comment: Thanks for your Help Mr. Tim... Now the code is working properly