# C# Syntax Error - INSERT INTO statement. Access Database.

Tags: c#, ms-access, syntax, insert, sql-insert

This is my code which I am getting syntax error in my `INSERT statement` for:

```
string strSql = "INSERT INTO Responses (OCR, DeadlineDate, OCR Title) VALUES ('"+textBox5.Text+"','"+textBox7.Text+"', '"+textBox6.Text+"')";

OleDbConnection newConn = new OleDbConnection(strProvider);
OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, newConn);

newConn.Open();
dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

any ideas?

Comment: Avoid your current injection vulnerability; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The column name `OCR Title` is invalid, you have to escape it using `[]` like `[OCR Title]`:

```
INSERT INTO Responses (OCR, DeadlineDate, [OCR Title]) VALUES( ...
```

---

Also, please try to use parametrized queries instead of concatenating the values:

```
string strSql = "INSERT INTO Responses (OCR, DeadlineDate, [OCR Title]) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

using (OleDbConnection newConn = new OleDbConnection(strProvider))
{
  using (OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, newConn))
  {
    dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OCR", textBox5.Text);
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("DeadlineDate", textBox7.Text);
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("[OCR Title]", textBox6.Text);
    newConn .Open();
    dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: Better to always put brackets around column names, when upgrading to a new database version who knows whether e.g. OCR becomes a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the syntax error isn't related to c# but to SQL statement.

Maybe you need escape on textBoxes values and text qualifier for "OCR Title" table name.