# Incorrect Syntax in Insert statement

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, syntax

Open and Close Connection:

```
OleDbConnection conn;
private void ConnectToDatabase()
{
    // Creates a connection to the database using an absolute path.
    conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +Server.MapPath("App_Data\\BookRatings.accdb"));
    // Opens the connection.
    conn.Open();
}
private void DisconnectDatabase()
{
    // The connection is closed.
    conn.Close();
}
```

Register User

```
 public void RegisterCustomer(string userName, string Address, string Tel, string Email, string Ques, string Ans, string Pass)
{
    // Connect to database.
    ConnectToDatabase();
    // Inserts the necessary values into the database.
    OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO user ([userName], [Address],[telephone], [emailAddress], [Password], [securityQuestion], [securityAnswer]) VALUES ('" + userName + "', '" + Address + "', '" + Tel + "', '" + Email + "', '" + Pass + "', '" + Ques + "', '" + Ans + "')");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    // The connection is closed.
    DisconnectDatabase();
}
```

Error Message

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in
>   INSERT INTO statement.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 100:        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); Line 101:        // The
>   connection is closed. Line 102:        DisconnectDatabase(); Line 103:
>   } Line 104:    [WebMethod]
>
> Source File: ***\bookClub\Service.aspx.cs    Line: 102
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [OleDbException (0x80040e14): Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.] 
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr) +1102900
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult) +247
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult) +189
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult) +58
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +162
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +107
>   Service.RegisterCustomer(String userName, String Address, String Tel,
>   String Email, String Ques, String Ans, String Pass) in
>   ***\bookClub\Service.aspx.cs:102    Register.btnRegister_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ***\bookClub\Register.aspx.cs:46
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9752490
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +196
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724

I don't understand why the close line is giving an issue? Or why it's crashing on insert...

Comment: Your code in vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, use SQL parameters instead of concatenating the parameters directly into the string.

Comment: Hi, did you know that your code is prone to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks? It could also be the source of the error you're getting though I think Tanner is more right in that regard. You should definitely not write your code concatenating the SQL like that, but instead use SQL parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**User** is a **[reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335)** in MS Access so simply update your SQL command to wrap `USER` in square brackets:

```
cmd.CommandText = (@"INSERT INTO [user] ([userName]....
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments, it's better to use a parameterized query to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Take a look at the answer on this question that shows you how you can do this:

### [Using parameters inserting data into access database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893956/57475)

Also, in that sample, it uses a `Using` block, which handles closing and disposing your connection, which is better than manually doing it. Your code would look something like this with parameters and a `Using` block:

```
conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +Server.MapPath("App_Data\\BookRatings.accdb"));
conn.Open();

// DbCommand also implements IDisposable
using (OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
   // create command with parameter placeholders
   cmd.CommandText = 
        @"INSERT INTO [user] ([userName], [Address],[telephone]....) " +
         "VALUES (@username, @address, @telephone,....)");

   // add named parameters
   cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
   {
        new OleDbParameter("@userName", userName),
        new OleDbParameter("@address", Address),
        new OleDbParameter("@telephone", Tel),
        ...
    };

    // execute
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: +1 - I think he also shouldn't have the extra methods ConnectToDatabase() and DisconnectDatabase() - a using block would be better..