# Saving DateTime value into microsoft access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I  am trying to save some data to access DB but the date is stored in incorrect format

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "insert into Clients(Name,Gender,PhoneNumber,ReciveServiceDate) 
values ('" + name_txtBox.Text + "','" + gender_comBox.Text + "'," 
+ long.Parse(phone_txtBox.Text) + "," 
+ (recive_dateTimePicker.Value).ToShortDateString() + ");";
```

[image: this is how date looks like in DB]

Comment: First thing to do: stop putting values directly into your SQL. Use parameterized SQL instead. That may very well fix your issue...

Comment: [C# Using Parameters inserting into Access DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)

Answer (score 0):

Listen to Jon's advice.

However, if you insist, you can do it like this:

```
+ (recive_dateTimePicker.Value).ToString("#yyyy'/'MM'/'dd#") + ");";
```