# insert data in MS Access Database

Tags: c#, database

my database in MS Access.i have a table named Admin.It has two attributes Username and Password. when i use insert query for inserting data then it show a message"syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." but i could not find out the problem . please help 
my code-

```
string cb = "INSERT INTO Admin(Username,Password) VALUES (@d1,@d2)";

command = new OleDbCommand(cb);

command.Connection = connection;

command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@d1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 20, "Username"));
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@d2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 30, "Password"));


command.Parameters["@d1"].Value = textusername.Text;
command.Parameters["@d2"].Value = textpassword.Text;



command.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Student Details", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
Add.Enabled = true;
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
    connection.Close();
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [using parameters inserting data into access database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through the *same problem* before.

And the **problem** is that you have used *attribute* `Password` which is the *reserved word* in Ms-Access. So, instead of using `Password` you can use something like

> Pword

And it will work fine.

Visit [Reserved words](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe) for the list of reserved words. It is the list for Access2007.

Hope it helps.

Comment: or putting brackets around the reserved word works, too.