# Insert error C# when inserting into access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I get an error when trying to insert a record into the database.

Here's the error:

[image]

The Code:

```
connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Booking] (TableID, BookingName, BookingNumber, BookingDate, PartySize) VALUES (@TableID, @BookingName, @BookingPhoneNumber, @BookingDate, @PartySize)";
            command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[] {
                    new OleDbParameter("@TableID", textBoxResTableID.Text),
                    new OleDbParameter("@BookingName", textBoxResName.Text),
                    new OleDbParameter("@BookingPhoneNumber", textBoxResNum.Text),
                    new OleDbParameter("@BookingDate", DateTime.Today),
                    new OleDbParameter("@PartySize", textBoxResPartySize.Text)
                });

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
```

The DB:

[image]

Comment: Forgot a `;` at the end of your `insert` statement?

Comment: @Kilanny That's not _have to_ as far as I know.

Comment: It could be due to incorrect parameter syntax. Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5894003/4795214

Comment: I know it may be a nonsense but...did you try to remove the "[" and "]" in your table name?

Comment: Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically instead of calling `Close` or `Dispose` methods manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like TABLEID may be a reserved word according to [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248738). To get round it enclose it in [].

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect this as a reserved keyword. Nice find. `+1`

Comment: @SonerGönül - it was a surprise to me as well. I almost didn't look as I thought it would be a dead end.

Comment: This solved it! I cannot believe it, was racking my brain! massive thank you!

Comment: @user5467760 - no problem. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and solved it adding parameters with following syntax:

```
 command.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.BSTR).Value = username;
```

**EDIT**:
pasted wrong command first.

Comment: But _why_ do you think this can solve OP's problem? What is the problem _anyway_?

Comment: I have no clue why. But with his method i had the same error. Not shure if it's the solution, but worked for me.