# C# Exception Overflow OleDB Error (Connecting My.ASP Web Form to an Access DB)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to connect my ASP.NET online registration form to  MS Access backend database. The connection code I'm using is

```
string myQuery = "INSERT INTO Parent([Username], [FirstName], [Surname], [Email], [Mobile], [Postcode], [Password]) values('" + Usernametb.Text + "','" + Firsttnametb.Text + "','" + Surnametb.Text + "','" + Emailtb.Text + "','" + Mobiletb.Text + "','" + Postcodetb.Text + "','" + Passwordtb.Text + "')";
string connString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = C:\Users\Z\Desktop\database\WorkDatabase.accdb";
try
{
    using (OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand())
        {
            myCommand.CommandText = myQuery;
            myConnection.Open();
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SuccReglbl.Text = "successful registration";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    SuccReglbl.Text = "Exception in DBHandler " + ex.Message;
}
```

I keep getting an error when I click on the "Register" button. saying "Exception in DBHandler Overflow"

Comment: [Mobile] is not an integer type in the table is it? - Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, you must rewrite to use paramaters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database

Comment: @AlexK. well, Mobile is the section in which the user types in their mobile number as an integer so yes it is. Also, this program is a private project, not one that I'm actually using online, so I dont think SQL injections can affect me

Comment: A phone number is not an integer its a string, make the column text.

Comment: As for SQL injection, when your code is working see what happens if you save the surname `o'keefe`

Comment: To disregard parameterizing your queries - which by the way is very easy - is not wise. It's helpful not only to prevent SQL Injection, but also for code readability.

Comment: That is not the entire exception message. The label is too short to contain the entire message. Put a break point in the catch block and update the question with the entire exception details. I think you may have stuffed a number too large for the data type into the database.