# C# Logging in system only works with first value of database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, authentication

I'm a beginner to C# so help would be much appreciated. I'm attempting to code a logging in system but I can only successfully log in with the first line of data (`username=admin` , `password=admin`). I can't seem to log in from other data in the database (`username=bryan` , `password=123`). This is the code.

```
    searchOLEDB.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM LOGIN where Username='" + LoginIDTextBox.Text + "' AND Password='" + LoginPasswordTextBox.Text + "'";
        searchOLEDB.Connection = cnnOLEDB;
        OleDbDataReader dr = searchOLEDB.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Logged In");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Password");
        }
        dr.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should never concatenate sql query like you did.  This will allow SQL Injection.  You should use parameters.

See this post for examples :
[using parameters inserting data into access database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database)

P.S. I would also recommend to not store password in clear into your database.