# Read Value from Database in TextBox when Combobox text changes VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, combobox, textbox, vb.net-2010

I have a list of Users Names in ComboBox and Some TextBoxes. When ComboBox text changes (i.e I select some username from ComboBox), The TextBoxes are filled with user details from the database.

I have code to achieve this in SQL Database. But these queries are not working with MsAccess database.

```
    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    Mysql.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;user=root;password=root;database=database"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        MysqlConn.open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query("select * from database.usernames where name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'")
        Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        READER = Command.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read
        TextBox1.Text = READER.GetString("name") 
        End While

    End Try
```

Comment: Unless you have lots of users, I strongly suggest that you don't query the database every time.  Just populate a `DataTable` with all the data and then bind it to both the `ComboBox` and the `TextBoxes`.  The `TextBoxes` will then update automatically when a selection is made in the `ComboBox`.

Comment: On what line is this code failing? Also, is this the code you are trying to use for MA Access?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer. Please don't get overwhelmed by it. ;)

**Broken code**

First of all, as I see it, the code you provided cannot work at all, because:

1. your `Query` variable is initialized in an invalid (or at least a very exotic) way. You probably want to use something like:

   ```
   Dim Query As String
   Query = "select * from database.usernames where name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
   ```

   or in a single line:

   ```
   Dim Query As String = "select * from database.usernames where name='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"
   ```
2. you try to assign the connection string to the `ConnectionString` property of a nonexistent `Mysql` variable. Or the variable exists because it is declared somewhere else, which might be a bug in your code snippet here. But I assume you want to assign the connection string to the `MysqlConn.ConnectionString` property instead.
3. you have not declared the `MysqlConn` and `Command` variables anywhere. You only just assign to them. (I will simply assume you have declared the variables correctly somewhere else in your code...)
4. the `IDataRecord` interface does not provide a `GetString(name As String)` method overload. So unless you have defined a custom extension method for it, you probably need to use the `IDataRecord.GetOrdinal(name As String)` method as well, or use the column index instead of the column name.

Anyway, the code you provided uses MySQL. So I assume that MySQL is the "SQL Database" you are using successfully. And that seems to work, as you say? Well... Hmmm... Then I will simply assume your code snippet is completely correct and works perfectly with MySQL... :/

**MS Access vs. MySQL**

Using MS Access requires other data access classes (probably the ones in namespace `System.Data.OleDb`) and another [connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/). You could take a look at this [ADO.NET OleDb example for MS Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples#oledb) in the Microsoft documentation.

You probably even have to update your SQL query, because every database system uses its own SQL dialect. You might want to consult the [Office documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Queries-93fb69b7-cfc1-4f3e-ab56-b0a01523bb50#ID0EAABAAA=SQL_syntax) for that. But your query is quite simple, so perhaps all you have to do to make it work with MS Access is:

- remove the database name and use only the table name, and
- delimit the `name` identifier (since it is a reserved keyword in MS Access).

I personally delimit all identifiers in my SQL queries, just to avoid unintended conflicts with reserved keywords. So I would personally use something like this:

```
select * from [usernames] where [name] = '...'
```

**Additional tips**

Also, I would like to provide you some additional (unrelated) tips regarding improving your code:

- Use [`Using`-statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) with variables of an `IDisposable` type as much as possible. Those types/classes do not implement that interface if there isn't a good reason for it, so I consider it not unimportant to call `Dispose` when you are done with such disposable objects (or using a `Using` statement to call `Dispose` implicitly).
- Use SQL parameters (if possible) to avoid [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. Look at [this StackOverflow question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893837/using-parameters-inserting-data-into-access-database) for an example of how to use SQL parameters with MS Access.

**Example**

You may take a look at the following code snippet. It might not provide a working example out-of-the-box, but you might get some useful/practical ideas from it:

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\\Data\\database.mdb;User Id=admin;Password="
Dim query As String = "select * from [usernames] where [name] = @Name"

Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Using command As New OleDbCommand(query)
        command.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ComboBox1.Text
        conn.Open()

        Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader
            If reader.Read Then
                textbox1.Text = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name"))
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```