# Vb.net Advance text box search

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm implementing a system and in that system, I want to search product while text changing on textbox in the datagridview. I've already done that part.

But I found out that search command only helping me to find the product 1st word of the cell. But I want to filter it with any of the selected cells.

Example:
In my datagridview there is a column `Product Name`. In that column, there Is a data as **Galaxy A20s**. Currently, I have to type on my search textbox starting as **Galaxy....** then only search result appearing. I want to modify the output like if I'm type **A20s** then also result should be filtered in the datagridview.

Any possibilities to do that in vb.net.

Here is the code which I'm using currently.

```
Try
            con = New OleDbConnection(cs)
            con.Open()
            cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT (ProductID) as [Product ID],(ProductName) as [Product Name],(Brand) as [Brand],(UnitPrice) as [Unit Price]  from ProductDB where ProductName like '" & txtSearch.Text & "%' order by ProductName", con)
            Dim myDA As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim myDataSet As DataSet = New DataSet()
            myDA.Fill(myDataSet, "ProductDB")
            dgFillProduct_Stock.DataSource = myDataSet.Tables("ProductDB").DefaultView

            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL `WHERE` clause has the `%` wildcard only at the end of the value:

```
ProductName like '" & txtSearch.Text & "%'
```

So the beginning of the `ProductName` needs to match, but the end can be anything.  If you want that functionality for both ends of the string value, you can simply put the wildcard on both ends:

```
ProductName like '%" & txtSearch.Text & "%'
```

---

**IMPORTANT:** Your code is currently open to SQL injection, which is not only a glaring security hole but also a very common source of bugs.  You should be using query parameters instead of directly placing user input in your query, since a malicious user could input *code* into your query.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5893837/328193) and its accepted answer are a great example of how to do this.